# Can I maximize UWP window programmatically?

Tags: c#, uwp

How to maximize uwp window on startup programmatically? I want maximize my window after startup, because it started minimized and suspended. Its possible?

Answer (score 0):

> How to maximize uwp window on startup programmatically? I want maximize my window after startup

Sure, you could make the app's window full screen when startup with setting [`ApplicationViewWindowingMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewwindowingmode?view=winrt-20348).

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
}
```

Comment: Its good method, but its not working for me :(. I'm launch my app when the user logs in to Windows and window start minimized. I want maximize it.

Comment: Do you means you want to call the window into foreground?

Comment: Yes, I want to call into foreground.

Comment: Yep, you could use the following code to bring app to foreground  `IEnumerable<AppListEntry> appListEntries = await Package.Current.GetAppListEntriesAsync();
            await appListEntries.First().LaunchAsync();`

Comment: I put this code after Window.Current.Activate(), it doesn`t seem work on startup.

Comment: Have you set break point to debug this line?

Comment: Why you place the code after `Window.Current.Activate()` but not after minimized method?